# Search a registry and add any missing keys and values not found using powershell

Tags: powershell, search, replace, registry

I have multiple registry keys with some having multiple values which if not found, need to be added.  I learned how to do this for a specific key and value but I am not sure how to do this for multiple keys and values.  I'm wanting to use powershell to acomplish this.

Example of the keys/values I have to add:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop]
"NoComponents"=dword:00000001
"NoAddingComponents"=dword:00000001
"NoHTMLWallPaper"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"ForceActiveDesktopOn"=dword:00000000
"NoActiveDesktopChanges"=dword:00000001
"NoActiveDesktop"=dword:00000001
"ShowSuperHidden"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum]
"{BDEADF00-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}"=dword:00000001
"{6DFD7C5C-2451-11d3-A299-00C04F8EF6AF}"=dword:40000021
"{0DF44EAA-FF21-4412-828E-260A8728E7F1}"=dword:00000020
```

The script that works but only does it one key/value at a time:

```
$KeyPath = "HKCU:\Registry\Key\Path"  
$ValueName = "name"  
$ValueData = "data"  
try{  
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $KeyPath -Name $valueName -ErrorAction Stop  
}  
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {  
    New-Item -Path $KeyPath -Force  
    New-ItemProperty -Path $KeyPath -Name $ValueName -Value $ValueData -Force  
}  
catch {  
    New-ItemProperty -Path $KeyPath -Name $ValueName -Value $ValueData -Type String -Force  
}
```

Comment: If all these keys and values need to be set why not just create a *.reg file and import it?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Olaf That... is actually a really good idea.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped ...  ... if possible I like to work according to the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).  